# .htaccess in root directory

Tags: apache-http-server, passwords, htaccess, subdomain

I have an apache webserver (shared hosting) where I have access to `/home/user`
If I place a `.htaccess` in `/home/user` it gets applied to all subdirectories.
The domain belonging to this has several subdomains that link to subdirectories of this webspace. I want to use authentication for some of the subdomains, whereas the main page should be password-free. e.g.:

- **example.com** --> `/home/user/mainPage` <- should not ask for a password
- **sub1.example.com** --> `/home/user/sub1` <- should not ask for a password
- **sub1.example.com** --> `/home/user/sub2` <- password protected

I am aware that I could place a .htaccess file in `/home/user/sub2`, to achieve this, but for various reasond I do not want to do so, but to control this from the "main" .htaccess file in `/home/user`

What seems to work is the following `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthUserFile /home/user/.passwords
AuthName "Please enter your ID and password"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

SetEnvIf HOST "sub2\.example\.com" deny
Order allow,deny
Deny from env=deny
Allow from all
Satisfy any
```

The question is now: **Is this a safe and secure method?** Or is there any way to gain access to sub2.example.com without knowing a correct username/password?

(It is safe to assume that there will be no `/home/user/sub2/.htaccess` file present or at least it will not overwrite the authentication part.)

I know that it would be much simpler to use `<Directory>`, but this is not allowed in .htaccess but only in the apache conf, which I am not allowed to edit.

Comment: You don't seem to care about the safe and secure method. Can you explain those various reasons for not doing it the simplest and secure method?

Comment: The main reason for not placing a .htaccess file in the sub2 directory is that in reality there are a few dozen directories which each would need an own file. There are already specific .htaccess files in there that do other things apart from authentication. Furthermore some of these .htaccess files arise from the CMS in this folder. It already happened that an CMS update replaced the .htaccess file with a new version where it then removed the auth part. Therefore I want to control authentication from the outside file. - using the apache config is not possible.

Comment: Why not create a directory for all your auth sites and put the .htaccess in this new dir ?

Comment: Oh, you are right. This is solution is so simple, but I did not saw it. Thank you.